# Access [formControl] under a <div> tag - Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: html, angular, typescript, form-control

In *typescript*:
`variableA = new FormControl('')`

In *html*:
`<input type = "text" [formControl] = "variableA">`

In html this works fine when it is written on the top (outside of all `< div >` tags).
When I write it under a `< div >` tag, then the program complains:

> Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

How to make the program be able to find this control under any `< div >` tag?

Comment: please provide code of a version with div usage

Comment: First guess is to make sure you've imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule. That does seem odd, though, that it only throws the error when there's a div.

Comment: please provide stackblitz link for your issue

Comment: I will provide code after some time. It is midnight where I live. @ Reza